# Android Host name may not be null

Tags: android, rest, httpclient

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers to those question didn't work for me.

I am trying to access a REST API, but when I try to connect I am getting this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null`

My URL is "http:localhost:3000/api/v1/users",

My code:

```
public String post(List<NameValuePair> data) {
    String result = null;
    HttpPost request;
    try {
        request = new HttpPost("http:localhost:3000/api/v1/users");
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            result = client.execute(request, handler);
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you check this in a browser http:localhost:3000/api/v1/users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/users
```

Android do not understand localhost line pc browser.

Answer (score 1):

`android` does not understand `localhost`. therefore replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2` and then try. it should work.

try this

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/users
```

Answer (score 0):

In first view i think there is some format issue with the passing of the URL

- change the url from

`http:localhost:3000/api/v1/users`

to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
```

**EDIT**

```
  And yes if you are running the emulator it is already taken the local host
```

[this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) give more info.